# BLE Advertising using custom packets

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

The description of `BluetoothLeAdvertiser` over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) says:

> This class provides a way to perform Bluetooth LE advertise operations, such as starting and stopping advertising. An advertiser **can broadcast up to 31 bytes of advertisement data represented by AdvertiseData**.

Does this mean that I can decide on what every single byte of the entire 31 bytes can contain? If yes, how? The methods listed in `AdvertiseData.Builder` are `addManufacturerData`, `addServiceData` and `addServiceUuid` which aren't useful in my case.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this on Android? I am trying to advertise a custom BLE advertisement packet using startAdvertising() and have an advertisement data type different than what AdvertiseData.Builder lets me add using its methods. Ideally I want to set each byte of the 31 bytes of the advertisement data on Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you can not add the data directly, thus you need to use the API to add the data. Then to save space you should set setIncludeDeviceName setIncludeTxPowerLevel both to false.

Then if you want to use craracteristics, etc. i.e. you want to make the BLE peripheral to provide additional data, and not just to be  a beacon. Then you must include the flags in the scan record. Flags will need take the normal parts i.e  type+lenght+data, thus it takes 3 bytes. If you are ok with just beacon, then you'll save the 3 bytes to be used with your own data.

I would assume that Service data will require some service UID to be added, so I would assume it takes space, and sofor the best option to use is the manufacturer data.

Manufacturer data takes the normal bytes for type & lenght, additionally android devices do appear to automatically add the manufacturer data, which takes additional 2 bytes.

So, for simple beacons, you could indeed have 31-4 = 27 bytes of payload delivered via the scan record.

Comment: I also have a fully working example for this ready (its actually same as using alt-beacons), but I do need to write a blog article for it before releasing it, and before that I really need to get one other blog article finalized. Hoping to get these done by tuesday :)

Comment: The blog article for the example is now on-line at: http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=154

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Sdk 4.3, but no longer Android support custom advertisement data in 5.0+ . You hava to call apis of `AdvertiseSetting` and `AdvertiseData` to fill up these 31 bytes.

Link for [AdvertiseSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html) and [AdvertiseData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

1. Use the startScan method of the BluetoothLeScanner class, with an appropriate ScanCallback callback - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html
2. When the onScanResult method of ScanCallback method is called, obtain the ScanResult object - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html
3. Do getScanRecord on it - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html
4. getAdvertiseFlags or getBytes on the ScanRecord object must surely give us what we need - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanRecord.html